# Using optional values in Auto Layout's visual format language

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I currently have a view constrained with the following visual format:

```
let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[myView]", options: [], views: ["myView": myView]
view.addConstraints(constraints)
```

I'm introducing an optional value that, if present at the time this constraint it added, should be used as spacing within this visual format. I'm currently doing this like so:

```
let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[myView]", options: [], views: ["myView": myView]
if let constraint = constraints.first, let spacing = optionalSpacing {
    constraint.constant = -spacing
}
view.addConstraints(constraints)
```

but this seems a little inelegant and it kills the major benefit of visual format in that you're not able to tell at a glance how the constraint is working.

I could also update the visual format string and metrics depending on whether or not my value is nil when this constraint is added:

```
var format: String
var metrics: [String: CGFloat]?
if let spacing = optionalSpacing {
    format = "V:|-(spacing)-[myView]"
    metrics = ["spacing": spacing]
} else {
    format = "V:|[myView]"
}
let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[myView]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: ["myView": myView]
```

but this is quite ugly.

I'm wondering if anyone has run into a similar issue before and how they typically solve it? I'm not seeing a lot of documentation online on how to handle optional values in the format strings. I'm assuming I can't just create a format string with the optional value (a la `"V:|-(optionalSpacing)-[myView]"`) without first checking if `optionalSpacing` is non-nil since the `metrics` dictionary has non-optional values.

Comment: You're not seeing a lot of documentation, because Visual Format Language was a very early attempt at making cumbersome constraint syntax easier. However, it Is now (in my opinion) so easy to use constraints that VFL is no longer needed (it was very limited to begin with anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this with the `nil` coalescing operator, `??`:

```
let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(spacing)-[myView]",
                                                 metrics: ["spacing": optionalSpacing ?? 0],
                                                 views: ["myView": myView])

view.addConstraints(constraints)   // or, perhaps better, `NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)`
```

This eliminates the need for the `if` statement.

---

Or, if you want to use the more contemporary anchor syntax:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: optionalSpacing ?? 0)
])
```